# VLC screen:// wont produce a file using :sout=

Tags: vlc

Why won't this produce a file? It does everything right but saving to an actual file .. I am using Linux, Vlc 1.1.9, compiled without skins2, qt or ncurses interfaces...

```
vlc :sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp4,acodec=mp4a,vb=800,scale=1}:std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst="~/file.mp4"} screen:// screen-fps=12 screen-caching=100
```

Note this also does the same thing - shows the screen:// fine, but will not output to a file:

```
vlc :sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=none,vb=800}:std{access=file,mux=avi,dst="/root/file.avi"} screen:// screen-fps=12 screen-caching=100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

> vlc -vvv (PORT (UDP, HTTP)) --ts-dump-file video.ts and add more commands
>   vlc -vvv (PORT (UDP, HTTP)) --sout-all file/ogg,mpg,ts:filename and add more commands

Thats above code shuld work!